# Allowing users to upload a jasperReport file and then compile it through a JSF page

Tags: web-applications, jsf-2, jasper-reports

I've been searching online for weeks now for a decent tutorial to help me with a JSF app I am working on

I need to allow users to upload Jasper Reports (.jasper or .jrxml) to a server, which I have done

now the problem I am having is how to let the user click a link in a file tree I have created and display the report in the browser in either pdf, excel, html, etc...

I see some tutorials around the net on how to compile them but it all seems to be VERY confusing and never exactly what I am looking for

I am using netbeans 6.9.1, JSF2.0, and Java in a JSF managed bean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To view a report you must first fill the report.  To fill the report you need a few things: a report file (.jrxml or .jasper), a parameter map, and a database connection.  If you use a .jrxml file you must first compile it. To compile a .jrxml file first load it:

```
JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(reportFile);
```

Then compile it:

```
JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);
```

The `reportFile` variable passed to the JRXmlLoader.load() method is a String with the file path to your .jrxml file location and file name ("C:\ReportFile\TestReport.jrxml").

Now that you've loaded and compiled your .jrxml file, you can fill your report. NOTE: if you use the .jasper file, you can jump right to this step. The `compiled_file_name` you would pass as a parameter is the file location and name of your .jasper file.

To fill a report you call the JasperFillManager and assign its results to a JasperPrint variable:

```
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(compiled_file_name, jasperParameter, jdbcConnection);
```

NOTE: if you are loading and compiling the .jrxml file, as shown above, you would just use `jasperReport` as the first parameter in the JasperFillManager.fillReport method, since that holds your compiled file.  The `compiled_file_name` is the reference to an already-compiled .jasper file. The filled report will be stored in `jasperPrint`, this is what you will pass around for various viewing and exporting options.

Now to view your file.  The easiest way to view it is to use the JasperViewer:

```
JasperViewer.viewReport(jasperPrint);
```

To export your report to a specific file format, use JasperExportManager:

```
JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, file_export_location);
```

The `file_export_location` is the file location and name where you will save the file.  There are various exporters in JasperExportManager, you should see them in NetBeans.  I export reports to .pdf.  To display them, I have my method send the view to another page which contains an `<iframe width="800px" height="500px" src="relative location of your file" />`.

Hope that helps.

You may also want to consider purchasing [The Ultimate Guide to JasperReports](http://www.jaspersoft.com/jasperreports-ultimate-guide) and [The Ultimate Guide to iReports](http://www.jaspersoft.com/ireport-ultimate-guide).  Both are pretty good guides to how to use JasperReports.

UPDATE:

As I said in my comment below, I don't recall where I got this list (I lost the link), but these are the .jar files I use in my projects (I've tried paring it down, but end up getting errors so I've taken the rookie-road of just including them all):

> ant-1.7.1, antlr-2.7.5,
>   barbecue-1.5-beta1, barcode4j-2.0,
>   batik-anim, batik-awt-util,
>   batik-bridge, batik-css, batik-dom,
>   batik-ext, batik-gvt, batik-parser,
>   batik-script, batik-svg-dom,
>   batik-svggen, batik-util, batik-xml,
>   batik-5.2, bsh-2.0b4,
>   commons-beanutils-1.8.0,
>   commons-collections-2.1.1,
>   commons-digester-1.7,
>   commons-javaflow-20060411,
>   commons-logging-1.0.4,
>   groovy-all-1.7.5, hibernate3,
>   hsqldb-1.8.0-10, iText-2.1.7,
>   jaxen-1.1.1, jcommon-1.0.15,
>   jdt-compiler-3.1.1, jfreechart-1.0.12,
>   jpa, jxl-2.6.10, log4j-1.2.15,
>   mondrian-3.1.1.12687, png-encoder-1.5,
>   poi-3.6, rhino-1.7R1, saaj-api-1.3,
>   serializer, servlet,
>   spring-beans-2.5.5, spring-core-2.5.5,
>   xalan-2.7.1, xercesImpl-.7.0,
>   xml-apis, xml-apis-ext

Hope that helps.

Comment: that all look great just one other quick question about this, if I don't want to save the report anywhere just display it, is there an option for that or do I have to save it each time and display it from there, then delete it afterwards if I choose?

Comment: oh sorry to bother again but a big thing is all the packages is there a place I can download all the jar files I will need or do I have to hunt and search all over the web for the proper packages?

Comment: I don't know of any way to display the report as a .pdf without first exporting it to .pdf format. On that note, I don't know of any way to export it into .pdf format without saving it as a .pdf file.

Comment: For the jar files, I seem to have lost the link to the page I used as a guide to what to include.  [This site](http://developers.sun.com/jsenterprise/archive/reference/techart/jse8/jasper_reports.html) should help, though.

Comment: @Sean
I am getting a strange error when I try to run the code now I have imported jasperreports-3.5.2.jar and all the libraries and jars the page you sent me says to bring in, and I am being told that engine.fill doesn't exist

**C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.0.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\Tutorial_sub_1298560554752_453619.java:5: package net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill does not exist
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.*;**

Comment: ok so I went to the jasper reports site, and downloaded the [latest project ZIP (4.0.0)](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jasperreports/files/jasperreports/JasperReports%204.0.0/jasperreports-4.0.0-project.zip/download), extract it, create a new library in netbeans, added all the jars from the dist, and lib folders in the jasperreports-4.0.0 project folder then added the library to my project, and BAM it worked